# How to get a variable value from a node in to a POD?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am writing a script which gets a pod ip and writes it into a python file in another pod
This is how i got my pod ip :

```
database=$(kubectl get svc database --namespace=namespace_name|sed -n -e '2p' |awk '{print $3}')
```

This is how i am trying to write it into a text file in another pod:

```
kubectl exec -it --namespace=namespace_name pod_name -- sed -i 's/ip_addr/$postgres/' conf.py
```

it gets executed but the python file is not edited

Comment: @Turing85 it is also perfectly fine here.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you are setting the database variable but using postgres in the pod for replacement. That will never work.

**Try this (notice the double quotes for variable expansion):**

```
kubectl exec --namespace=namespace_name pod_name -- sed -i "s/ip_addr/$postgres/" conf.py
```

**Another option:**

Create the file locally with all the values replaced then just copy the file to the pod using

```
kubectl cp --namespace=namespace_name <local-path>/conf.py pod_name:<pod-path>/conf.py
```